# How can we conclude to this cost?

Tags: sorting, mergesort

I want to find the cost of the following algorith of the Merge Sort:

```
  Merge(A,p,q,r)
       n1=q-p+1;
       n2=r-q;
       We create the sequences:
       L[1 .... n1+1] and R[1.... n2+1]
       for i<-1 to n1
           L[i]<-A[p+i-1]
       for j<-1 to n2
            R[j]<-A[q+j]
       L[n1+1]<-oo  ,   R[n2+1]<-oo   ( sentinel elements )

       Composition:
       i<-1, j<-1
       for k<-p to r
          if L[i]<=R[j] then
              A[k]<-L[i]
              i<-i+1
          else
              A[k]<-R[j]
              j<-j+1


    MERGESORT(A,p,r)
       if p<r then
          q<-floor((p+r)/2)
          MERGESORT(A,p,q)
          MERGESORT(A,q+1,r)
          Merge(A,p,q,r)
```

According to my textbook,the cost is T(n)=2T(n/2)+cn,n>1 and T(n)=c,n=1

but I haven't really understood how we can conclude to this relation.

Could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) // two reucrsive calls, each on half the array
     + cn      // the cost of merge. Merge runs in linear time.
```

We can write this as

```
T(n) = O(nlogn)
```

Because

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + cn 
     = 4T(n/4) + cn + cn 
     = 8T(n/8) + cn + cn + cn 
     = ... (after log times)
     = n*T(n/n) + cn + cn + cn + ... + cn (where cn appears log(n) times)
     = c*logn*n
```

Comment: To conclude that  the Merge function has cost O(n),do we just count the number of times that the for loops run and we ignore the number of controls and assignments or do we have to take these also into consideration?

Comment: It doesn't matter, in both cases you get a result that is a linear function on the number of input elements.

Comment: Because of the fact that the cost of the assigments and controls are just constants and we just take into consideration the term with the highest degree?

Comment: Or the sum of the constants, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Tohava Also,if n=1,it is T(n)=c,according to my textbook..Why isn't it T(1)=1,since at this case,we only check if p<r,that is not true?

Comment: Maybe the `p<r` check requires more than one action? Once again, don't try to count actions accureatly, just get the asymptote

Answer (score 1):

In every recursion you are splitting a problem *T(n)* of size **n** into *two* problems *T(n/2)* of size **n/2**, so you get **2*T(n/2)**. After the last recursion you have to merge the sorted lists back together. Merging sorted lists is done in *O(n)*, which is equivalent to *c*n*.

So the complete costs are *T(n)=2T(n/2)+cn* .

Comment: To conclude that  the Merge function has cost O(n),do we just count the number of times that the for loops run and we ignore the number of controls and assignments or do we have to take these also into consideration?

Comment: To merge two sorted lists you just have to run over both lists exactly one time.